# how to implement this soft-keyboard effect in a listView

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I would like to find out more about that feature to implement it in a listview for each item.

so, how is called the event responsible to show the popups in the soft-keyboard when the finder is moved over the keys without untouching it like the GIF below?

[image]

Assuming the keys A, S, and D are items of listview oriented vertically, what could I use to implement that effect on that?

Comment: Add a screenshot to make it clear what you're searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can you QuickAction for that or the QuickAction 3D. search google "QuickAction Android"